# im calling clearRect but its not making any change

Tags: canvas

this is an easy code, if someone could explain to me why this aint clearing the canvas

```
var x = 0;
var y = 100;
function draw(){
    context.clearRect(0,0,300,300);
    context.beginPath;
    
    context.rect(x,y,100,100);
    context.fillStyle = "Red";
    
    context.fill();


    x+=10;
    if(x>250){
        x-= 200;
    }
}
setInterval(draw ,50);
```

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YYCh.png)

Comment: For me it does work if I add `context.fillStyle = "White";` before the `clearRect()`

Comment: beginPath is a function to call it you need the parentheses `ctx.beginPath()`